# CakePHP - I can't get App::uses() to find my class

Tags: cakephp

I have some custom classes that just contain static utility methods:

```
app/Lib/Utility/AppString.php
```

Cake can't find the class though.  I have tried:

```
// app/Config/bootstrap.php

App::uses('AppString', 'Utility');
App::uses('AppString', 'Lib/Utility');
App::uses('AppString', 'Lib');
```

I don't know what I should be putting to get Cake to find the classes.  I am doing this in my bootstrap.php because the classes are essential to the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that I was correct to use:

```
App::uses('AppString', 'Utility');
```

However, there was a syntax error in my class AppString.  This causes confusing messages, as PHP will report a fatal error that the class could not be found, when in fact it's just because of the error in the file.

Comment: thanks, I would have kept looking for hours elsewhere. I had the same thing happen.

Comment: good reccomendation. In my case I also had a conflict with namespaces and use native statements. I solved removing namespaces and uses